# Get the net total of a history table in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get the net total of each billings based on his last record (`Billings_History`), if no history simply displaying the same information from the source table (`Billings`).

Billings

```
BILLCOD TOTAL
BILL01  15.00
BILL02  10.00
BILL03  15.00
BILL04  26.00
BILL05 294.00
```

Billings_History

```
HISTORYCOD  BILLCOD TOTAL
H001        BILL01  36.00 
H002        BILL01   5.00 -- USE Latest HISTORYCOD in case when BILLCOD is duplicated
H003        BILL03  50.00
H004        BILL05 204.00
```

I need this Result

```
BILL01  -10.00
BILL03   35.00
BILL05  -90.00
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative to the solution given by @jarlh :

```
SELECT b.BILLCOD AS BILLCOD, t.TOTAL - b.TOTAL AS TOTAL
FROM Billings b INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT bh1.HISTORYCOD, bh1.BILLCOD, bh1.TOTAL
    FROM Billings_History bh1 INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT BILLCOD, MAX(HISTORYCOD) AS MAXHISTORYCOD
        FROM Billings_History
        GROUP BY BILLCOD
    ) bh2
    ON bh1.HISTORYCOD = bh2.MAXHISTORYCOD AND bh1.BILLCOD = bh2.BILLCOD
) t
ON b.BILLCOD = t.BILLCOD
```

Answer (score 1):

The sub-select uses `NOT EXISTS` to return the latest `TOTAL` for each `BILLCOD` in the `Billings_History` table.

That result is right side table to a `LEFT JOIN`. Use `COALESCE` to set value 0 if no row in right side table.

```
select b.BILLCOD, coalesce(bh.TOTAL,0) - b.TOTAL 
from Billings b
left join (select BILLCOD, TOTAL
           from Billings_History bh1
           where not exists (select 1 from Billings_History bh2
                             where bh2.BILLCOD = bh1.BILLCOD
                               and bh2.HISTORYCOD > bh1.HISTORYCOD)) bh
    on b.BILLCOD = bh.BILLCOD
```